# Log execve's, along with parent process argv?

Tags: linux, auditd

I'm trying to figure out if I can decomission an old server. I need the information about automated processes running there. So far I tried the following:

```
auditctl -a exit,always -F arch=b64  -S execve -k any-commands
```

At log analysis stage, I discovered two pieces of context missing:

1. How did those programs get executed? What process was their parent and what was its argv?
2. Where did the stdin/stdout go? Ideally I'd love to see the shell command reconstructed, but I know I'm probably asking for too much, so at least having pipe descriptor ID would do (so that I can try to re-construct it with my own scripts).

How can I approach such a problem?

Comment: That information isn't available in the execve system call. Perhaps you should be tracking other syscalls, like clone or open.

Answer (score 1):

The `execve` system call replaces the current process. If a program wants to retain control after starting another program, it needs to create a new process first (using `fork` or `vfork`) that then calls `execve`.

The open file descriptors and permissions are taken over when the program image is replaced in `execve` (except those marked with the `CLOEXEC` flag), so open files are inherited from the parent process during `fork`, then modified between `fork` and `execve` (e.g. using `dup2`), and then finally filtered during the `execve` call.

So getting a complete picture from audit data will be difficult.